# ¿Por qué al añadir setTimeOut a esta función, se ejecuta dos veces?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Un juego que consiste en tocar dos cartas ocultas y si son las mismas se destapan. El juego termina cuando todas están destapadas.

Pues bien tengo esta función que comprueba que si todas están destapadas, entonces emite una simple alerta de "You Win"

```
function checkWin()
{
  var testing = Array.from(cards)
   // checkIfAll comprueba si estás destapadas:
  const checkIfAll = testing.every(card => card.classList.contains('flip'));

  // Si están destapadas emite la alerta:
  if (checkIfAll){
    alert("You win!")
  }
}
```

El problema es que si coloco la función checkWin() directamente después que la última carta sea destapada, la alerta aparece antes de que la ultima carta se destape ya que tarda un poco porque tiene transición css, por lo que la pongo en setTimeOut de 2 segundos:

```
function blockCard() {

  firstCard.removeEventListener('click', doFlip);
  secondCard.removeEventListener('click', doFlip);

  firstCard.classList.add('no-border')
  audio.play();
  secondCard.classList.add('no-border')

  // Comprueba que el jugador ha ganado, pero con un retraso de 2 segundos:
  setTimeout(checkWin, 2000)

  resetBoard();
}
```

El problema ahora es que al ponerle el retraso de 2 segundos, parece que entonces la función blockCard() se ejecuta otra vez? Y entonces la alerta aparece otra vez? No estoy seguro.

Éste es el código con menos cartas, el código completo se puede ver aquí (sin imágenes):  https://jsfiddle.net/c8yp35jg/

```js
let hasFlippedCard = false;
let lockBoard = false;
let firstCard;
let secondCard;

const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card');

// Win celebration:
function checkWin() {

  var testing = Array.from(cards)
  const checkIfAll = testing.every(card => card.classList.contains('flip'));

  if (checkIfAll) {
  debugger;
    alert("You win!")
  }
}

// Effect function:
function doFlip() {

  if (lockBoard) return;
  if (this === firstCard) return;

  this.classList.add('flip');

  if (!hasFlippedCard) {

    hasFlippedCard = true;
    firstCard = this;
    return;
  }
  secondCard = this;

  checkForMatch();
}


function blockCard() {

  firstCard.removeEventListener('click', doFlip);
  secondCard.removeEventListener('click', doFlip);

  firstCard.classList.add('no-border')
  audio.play();
  secondCard.classList.add('no-border')

  // Comprueba que el jugador ha ganado, pero con un retraso de 2 segundos:
  setTimeout(checkWin, 2000)

  resetBoard();
}

function checkForMatch() {
  let isMatch = firstCard.dataset.framework === secondCard.dataset.framework;

  isMatch ? blockCard() : resetCard();
}

function resetCard() {
  lockBoard = true;

  setTimeout(() => {
    firstCard.classList.remove('flip');
    secondCard.classList.remove('flip');

    resetBoard();
  }, 550);
}

function resetBoard() {
  [hasFlippedCard, lockBoard] = [false, false];
  [firstCard, secondCard] = [null, null];
}

(function shuffle() {
  cards.forEach(card => {
    let randomPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12);
    card.style.order = randomPos;
  });
})();

cards.forEach(card => card.addEventListener('click', doFlip));
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins&display=swap");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arimo&display=swap");
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: no-repeat url("../img/Purpink.jpg");
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

#game-container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.card {
  width: calc(25% - 10px);
  height: calc(47% - 10px);
  margin: 5px;
  position: relative;
  transform: scale(1);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform .5s;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

.no-border {
  box-shadow: none;
  transition: box-shadow 1.3s ease-in-out;
}

.card:active {
  transform: scale(0.85);
  transition: transform .1.5s;
}

.card.flip {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.front,
.back {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 5px;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.front {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  color: #F8F0FB;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

/* Button Styling */

*,
*:after,
*:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

button {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  color: #F8F0FB;
  font-size: 19px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 85vh;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);
}

span {
  display: block;
  padding: 25px;
}

button::before,
button::after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
  background: #F8F0FB;
}

span::before,
span::after {
  content: "";
  width: 2px;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
  background: #F8F0FB;
}

button:hover::before,
button:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
}

button:hover span::before,
button:hover span::after {
  height: 100%;
}

.btn-2::before,
.btn-2::after {
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

.btn-2 span::before,
.btn-2 span::after {
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

.btn-2::before {
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.btn-2::after {
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.btn-2 span::before {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.btn-2 span::after {
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.btn-2:hover::before,
.btn-2:hover::after {
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

.btn-2:hover span::before,
.btn-2:hover span::after {
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  padding-top: 150px;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 25%;
  ;
  animation-name: animatetop;
  animation-duration: 0.8s
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Matching Game</h1>
</header>

<audio id="audio" src="../sounds/trap-clap-08.wav"></audio>
<div id="game-container">
  <div class="card" data-framework="chill">
    <img class="front" src="https://via.placeholder.com/115x100?text=chill" />
    <img class="back" src="https://via.placeholder.com/115x100?text=Back" />
  </div>
  <div class="card" data-framework="chill">
    <img class="front" src="https://via.placeholder.com/115x100?text=chill" />
    <img class="back" src="https://via.placeholder.com/115x100?text=Back" />
  </div>
  <div class="card" data-framework="focus">
    <img class="front" src="https://via.placeholder.com/115x100?text=focus" />
    <img class="back" src="https://via.placeholder.com/115x100?text=Back" />
  </div>
  <div class="card" data-framework="focus">
    <img class="front" src="https://via.placeholder.com/115x100?text=focus" />
    <img class="back" src="https://via.placeholder.com/115x100?text=Back" />
  </div>
  <div class="card" data-framework="funk">
    <img class="front" src="https://via.placeholder.com/115x100?text=funk" />
    <img class="back" src="https://via.placeholder.com/115x100?text=Back" />
  </div>
  <div class="card" data-framework="funk">
    <img class="front" src="https://via.placeholder.com/115x100?text=funk" />
    <img class="back" src="https://via.placeholder.com/115x100?text=Back" />
  </div>
  <div class="card" data-framework="hiphop">
    <img class="front" src="https://via.placeholder.com/115x100?text=hiphop" />
    <img class="back" src="https://via.placeholder.com/115x100?text=Back" />
  </div>
  <div class="card" data-framework="hiphop">
    <img class="front" src="https://via.placeholder.com/115x100?text=hiphop" />
    <img class="back" src="https://via.placeholder.com/115x100?text=Back" />
  </div>
  
  

</div>


<button id="resetGame" class="btn-2" onClick="window.location.reload()"><span>New Game</span></button>
```

Comment: ¿Puedes actualizar el fiddle con tu problema o crear un `snippet` para verlo? No consigo reproducir el error. Por si mismo el `setTimeout` no debería de iterar...

Comment: Quizás `sleep()` antes de llamar a `checkWin()` te pueda servir.

Comment: Debes estar llamándote sin darte cuenta dos veces a la función.

Comment: @Exe No existe un sleep en Javascript

Comment: No consigo reproducir el error con tu fiddle, pero te lo he arreglado para que se puedan ver imágenes... lo pondré en la pregunta

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Escenario:

Todas las cartas menos 4 están giradas, por tanto el usuario:

1. hace girar la primera de las 4 restantes: se llama al método `doFlip()`.
2. hacer girar la segunda carta: se llama de nuevo al método `doFlip()`.
3. Tenemos una coincidencia! Esta segunda llamada a `toFlip()` provoca una llamada al método `blockCard()`;
4. El método `blockCard()` ejecuta el `setTimeout`, dentro de dos segundos se comprobará si todas las cartas se han girado y la partida ha terminado.
5. El usuario ve que sólo quedan dos cartas por girar, que necesariamente son iguales, hace click en las dos en menos de dos segundos.
6. Se repiten los pasos 3 y 4
7. El primer timeout se completa: ¡Has ganado!
8. El segundo timeput se completa: ¿¡Has ganado!?

Puedes comprobar que es el problema porque cuando sólo quedan dos cartas para girar, si esperas un par de segundos antes de girarlas el error no pasa.

Solución: Llama a `checkWin` sin usar `setTimeout`. Dentro de `checkWin`, si se ha ganado, usa un `setTimeout` para lanzar el *alert*.